# iOS - Store credit/debit card in encrypted form on server from ios app and decrypt it from the app again. How can I manage it most securely?

Tags: ios, swift, security, encryption, cryptography

I have static key in my iOS application. By using that key I am encrypting credit/debit cards and sends it to server for future use. And I am using same key for decryption of card.

Now I can't use dynamic key by any key generation algorithm as I want to decrypt my card later on. So, Every time I require same key.

So, My question is how should I store my key or where I should store my key as it'll be most secure? or Can I manage this stuff by generating dynamic key every time? If yes then how?

Many iOS applications like Amazon, Uber etc are storing the card information in their server! How they people are managing this stuff?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to ask this question then you are already breaking PCI compliance.  Your customers credit card information should never touch your server, encrypted or otherwise.  Most payment gateways handle this for you.  There is very little reason why you should be doing this yourself.

If you **do** need to handle this yourself, and there are very few cases where you do, simply symmetrically encrypting the card information in your app is not the way to do it.  Literally anyone who can download your app can decrypt other customers credit card information.

The correct approach would be to transport card information to your server secured with TLS, then encrypting and storing the key information in a HSM server side.  If you can't manage this, then you are not PCI compliant and will be legally responsible.

If your business operates, or has service available to customers in the EU, then you could suffer **very** heavy fines for poor handling of consumer credit card information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am curious for any iOS specific solution(If anything is possible)! If I can manage it within my server then it'll be great else I have planned to store it in payment gateway! Again thanks a lot! Really appreciate the answer :)